# Chrome does not show my website

Tags: javascript

website does not loading javascript on Chrome i do not know why, while Mozilla shows it properly.
do not know whats wrong.

website main function 
1. get geo-location of client (first lat long and find nearest city)
2. get weather data with openweathermap API
3. display it in website.

[Link to website](http://codepen.io/edenlt/pen/rWemYb)

```js
 // Taken and modifed from https://roessland.com/blog/free-code-camp-3-a-random-quote-machine/
$(document).ready(function () {
//  geo

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
var lat_lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon_lon = position.coords.longitude; 
//google maps
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latitude = lat_lat;
var longitude = lon_lon;
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
geocoder.geocode({       
        latLng: latLng     
        }, 
        function(responses) 
        {     
           if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
           {        // starting weather API
              var addressas = (responses[2].address_components[4].long_name);  //get address

               $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+addressas+"&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=5b18b37cb72f7fbdc5714dc6b3798007 ",function(result){
                  // Get and convert temperatures from celsius to farenghate
                  
                  var curentDayTemp = Math.round(result.list[0].temp.day);
                  var curentNightTemp = Math.round(result.list[0].temp.night);
                  var secDayTemp = Math.round(result.list[1].temp.day);
                  var secNightTemp = Math.round(result.list[1].temp.night);
                  var thirdDayTemp = Math.round(result.list[2].temp.day);
                  var thirdNightTemp = Math.round(result.list[2].temp.night);
                  var forthDayTemp = Math.round(result.list[3].temp.day);
                  var forthNightTemp = Math.round(result.list[3].temp.night);

                  // feting celsius to far                  
                  function toFar(cels) {
                   return cels*1.8 + 32;
                    }

                  $("p.city").html(result.city.name);
                  $("div.today > p.cur-weather").html(result.list[0].weather[0].description); 
                  $("div.today > p.max-temp-cel").html("Day "+ curentDayTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.today > p.min-temp-cel").html("Night "+ curentNightTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.today > p.max-temp-far").html("Day "+ Math.round(toFar(curentDayTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.today > p.min-temp-far").html("Night "+ Math.round(toFar(curentNightTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.today > p.humidity").html("Humidity: "+result.list[0].humidity);
                  $("div.today > p.wind-speed").html("Wind speed: "+ result.list[0].speed);
                  $("div.today > p.pressure").html("Pressure: "+ result.list[0].pressure); 
                  $("div.today > p.clouds").html("Clouds: "+ result.list[0].clouds+"%");
                   // 2nd day
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.cur-weather").html(result.list[1].weather[0].description); 
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.max-temp-cel").html("Day "+ secDayTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.min-temp-cel").html("Night "+ secNightTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.max-temp-far").html("Day "+ Math.round(toFar(secDayTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.min-temp-far").html("Night "+ Math.round(toFar(secNightTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.humidity").html("Humidity: "+result.list[1].humidity);
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.wind-speed").html("Wind speed: "+ result.list[1].speed); 
                  $("div.2nd-day > p.clouds").html("Clouds: "+ result.list[1].clouds+"%");
                  // 3rd day
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.cur-weather").html(result.list[2].weather[0].description); 
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.max-temp-cel").html("Day "+ thirdDayTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.min-temp-cel").html("Night "+ thirdNightTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.max-temp-far").html("Day "+ Math.round(toFar(thirdDayTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.min-temp-far").html("Night "+ Math.round(toFar(thirdNightTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.humidity").html("Humidity: "+result.list[2].humidity);
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.wind-speed").html("Wind speed: "+ result.list[2].speed); 
                  $("div.3rd-day > p.clouds").html("Clouds: "+ result.list[2].clouds+"%");
                  // 4th day
                  $("div.4th-day > p.cur-weather").html(result.list[3].weather[0].description); 
                  $("div.4th-day > p.max-temp-cel").html("Day "+ forthDayTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.4th-day > p.min-temp-cel").html("Night "+ forthNightTemp+" &#8451;");
                  $("div.4th-day > p.max-temp-far").html("Day "+ Math.round(toFar(forthDayTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.4th-day > p.min-temp-far").html("Night "+ Math.round(toFar(forthNightTemp))+" &#8457;");
                  $("div.4th-day > p.humidity").html("Humidity: "+result.list[3].humidity);
                  $("div.4th-day > p.wind-speed").html("Wind speed: "+ result.list[3].speed); 
                  $("div.4th-day > p.clouds").html("Clouds: "+ result.list[3].clouds+"%");
                    


                    // add dates
                    var today = new Date();
                    var toD = today.getDate();
                    var toM = today.getDate()+1;
                    var toAT = today.getDate()+2;
                    var toATT = today.getDate()+3;
                  var mm = today.getMonth();
                  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+toD;
tomorow = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+toM;
dayAfterTomorow = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+toAT;
dayAfterTomorowTomorow = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+toATT;
$("p.today-time").html(today);
$("p.sec-time").html(tomorow);
$("p.thrd-time").html(dayAfterTomorow);
$("p.forth-time").html(dayAfterTomorowTomorow);

                   
            $('.celsius').click(function() {
              var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('fahrenheit celsius');
    if($this.hasClass('fahrenheit')){
      $this.text('Fahrenheit');     
    } else {
      $this.text('Celsius');
    }
    $('.far-cel-toggle').toggleClass('hide show');
});
            
        
                    // Add class to body for background
                    var str = result.list[0].weather[0].id;
                    var chClass = document.getElementById("tarback");
                    chClass.className += "a"+str;    
                     // Add class for weather icons
                     var str1 = result.list[1].weather[0].id;
                     var str2 = result.list[2].weather[0].id;
                     var str3 = result.list[3].weather[0].id;
                    var icClass = document.getElementById("wi-ic");
                    icClass.className += "wi wi-owm-"+str;
                    var icClass = document.getElementById("wi-ic1");
                    icClass.className += "wi wi-owm-"+str1;
                    var icClass = document.getElementById("wi-ic2");
                    icClass.className += "wi wi-owm-"+str2;
                    var icClass = document.getElementById("wi-ic3");
                    icClass.className += "wi wi-owm-"+str3;
                    


        });

             } 
           else 
           {       
             alert('Not getting Any address for given latitude and longitude.');     
           }   
        }

);

});

} 

});
```

```css
/* thunderstorm */
body.a200, body.a201, body.a202, body.a210, body.a211, body.a212, body.a221, body.a230, body.a231, body.a232 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/thunderstorm.jpg);
}
/* Drizzle */
body.a300, body.a301, body.a302, body.a310, body.a311, body.a312, body.a313, body.a314, body.a321 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/drizzle.jpg);
}
/* Rain */
body.a500, body.a501, body.a502, body.a503, body.a504, body.a511, body.a520, body.a521, body.a522, body.a531 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/rain.jpg);
}
/* Snow */
body.a906, body.a903, body.a600, body.a601, body.a602, body.a611, body.a612, body.a615, body.a616, body.a620, body.a621, body.a622 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/snow.jpg);
}
/* Atmosphere */
body.a701, body.a711, body.a721, body.a731, body.a741, body.a751, body.a761, body.a762, body.a771, body.a781 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/fog.jpg);
}
/* Clear sky */
body.a800 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/clear-sky.jpeg);
}
/* Clouds */
body.a801, body.a802, body.a803, body.a804 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/clouds.jpg);
}
/* hurricane */
body.a961, body.a960, body.a902, body.a962, body.a900, body.a901 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/hurricane.jpg);
}
/* hot */
body.a904 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/hot.jpg);
}
/* windy */
body.a905, body.a954, body.a955, body.a956, body.a958, body.a957, body.a959 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/windy.jpg);
}
/* Clam */
body.a951, body.a952, body.a953 {
 background-image: url(https://simsim.lt/fcc/img/clam.jpg);
}
.block-warp {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 2% 0 0 0;
 padding: 1%;
}
.last-3 p, .last-3 i {
    color: darkseagreen;
}
.strong {font-weight: bold;}
.main i, .main p { color: beige; }
.icon-wrap, .icon,
.icon-wrap, .wi {
    font-size: 50px;
padding: 0% 0 1% 0;}
.link {text-align: center;}
.hide {display: none;}

#buttonas{
    display: block;
    margin:1% auto;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
border: black 3px solid;
width: 10%;
line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>  
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://simsim.lt/fcc/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://simsim.lt/fcc/css/weather-icons.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
    </script> 
 
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>        
    <body id="tarback" class="">
      <div class="warp container-fluid">
        <div class="link strong red"><a class="test" href="https://freecodecamp.com">Free code camp</a> and <a href="http://openweathermap.org/">Open Weather map API</a></div>
        <div>
          <button id="buttonas" class="celsius">Celsius</button>
          </div>
          <div class="block-warp"> <!-- Main block-->
            <div class="row text-center">
              <div class="today main strong">
                <p class="today-time"></p>
                <p class="city h1"></p>
                <p class="cur-weather h3"></p> <!-- curent temp -->
                <i id="wi-ic" class=""></i>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 today col-md-offset-5">
                 <p class="far-cel-toggle curent-temp-min min-temp-cel show"></p>
                 <p class="far-cel-toggle curent-temp-min min-temp-far hide"></p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 today">
                  <p class="far-cel-toggle curent-temp-max max-temp-cel show"></p>
                  <p class="far-cel-toggle curent-temp-max max-temp-far hide"></p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 today col-md-offset-5">
                 <p class="humidity"></p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 today">
                  <p class="wind-speed"></p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 today col-md-offset-5">
                 <p class="clouds"></p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 today">
                  <p class="pressure"></p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              
              </div> <!-- today ends -->
            </div><!-- row ends -->
          </div><!-- inner warp ends -->
          <div class="last-3">
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 block-warp">
              <div class="2nd-day">
                <p class="sec-time"></p>
                <p class="cur-weather h4"></p> <!-- curent temp -->
                <i id="wi-ic1" class=""></i>
                <p class="cur-temp"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle min-temp-cel show"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle min-temp-far hide"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle max-temp-cel show"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle max-temp-far hide"></p>
                <p class="humidity"></p>
                <p class="wind-speed"></p>
                <p class="clouds"></p>
              </div><!-- 2nd day ends -->
            </div><!-- coll ends -->
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 block-warp">
              <div class="3rd-day">
                <p class="thrd-time"></p>
                <p class="cur-weather h4"></p> <!-- curent temp -->
                <i id="wi-ic2" class=""></i>
                <p class="cur-temp"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle min-temp-cel show"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle min-temp-far hide"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle max-temp-cel show"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle max-temp-far hide"></p>
                <p class="humidity"></p>
                <p class="wind-speed"></p>
                <p class="clouds"></p>
              </div><!-- 3rd day ends -->
            </div><!-- coll ends -->
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 block-warp">
              <div class="4th-day">
                <p class="forth-time"></p>
                <p class="cur-weather h4"></p> <!-- curent temp -->
                <i id="wi-ic3" class=""></i>
                <p class="cur-temp"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle min-temp-cel show"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle min-temp-far hide"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle max-temp-cel show"></p>
                <p class="far-cel-toggle max-temp-far hide"></p>
                <p class="humidity"></p>
                <p class="wind-speed"></p>
                <p class="clouds"></p>
              </div><!-- 4th day ends -->
            </div><!-- coll ends -->
          </div><!-- row ends -->
        </div>
      </div>
      
    
    </body>  
 
  </html>
```

Comment: The restrictions are set in place for a reason. Please don't post your codepen here as code just to get by the restrictions. Actually post code *here*...

Comment: Sorry Andrew as you see im new here, and just looking for help, where i can post address? in comments?  or just post whole code here?

Comment: Posting the URL is fine, but don't post it as code, post it as a regular link. Then include relevant code *in the post*

Comment: ok i do not know what wrong im doing but it do not let me post link till there is no code, after im inserting code its says that its most is code and do not letting me submit

Comment: You have to select your code and press `Ctrl+K` or the code button to format it. The error you get is probably because you did not format your code.

Comment: @EdenLT Then you need more non-code content in your question. Describe the problem better, explain what you are doing, and **only include relevant code**. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @nicovank No, it's actually the opposite. They probably have way too much code, and SO is telling them to add more non-code content.

Comment: ok looks like i managed put it into spinet.
explained what website have to do in post. in mozila working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use Geolocation in Chrome fom a secure website (i.e. HTTPS protocol):

> [See documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp):
>
> > **Note**: As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.

Comment: yes, i just upload`ed page to my website and its working if allowing load unsafe content.

just openweathermap API have http access for free users